# How do i apply 'ScrollView' with other layouts in Android?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

Using scrollView causes my application to crash. I need a scrollview as all of the content is not visible in the screen, it is down past the end of the screen. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:text="RECORD MATCH DETAILS"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                        android:text="Home Team:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

                <TextView
                        android:text="Away Team:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

                <TextView
                        android:text="Select Date:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                        android:text="Select Time:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: paste your logcats error log and some of the relevent code

Comment: what does "my application crashes" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your layout is invalid because your TextViews do not specify a layout_width and height. This is explained in the stacktrace from the crash of your app

Answer (score 0):

Got It!!

Thanks for all your help.

My linearlayout layout_height needed to be 'wrap_content'.
I also entered the data in table format.
Here is my new code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:text="RECORD MATCH DETAILS"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Home Team:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Away Team:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Select Date:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Select Time:" 
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow >
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/btnCreateMatch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="Create Match"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks again!